# findViewById inside of onClick retuns null value

Tags: java, android

So I have the following fuction inside an adapter class. I want my Toast to print the text of a TextView when a certain icon is clicked but turns out I'm unable to get that TextView inside of my onClick function.

```
public TitleParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_routines, viewGroup, false);
    ImageView playIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playRoutine);
    playIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView rutNameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.parentTitle);
            String rutName = rutNameView.getText().toString(); //THIS crashes because rutNameView is null
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), rutName + " was played",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    return new TitleParentViewHolder(view);
}
```

I've tried defining rutName outside of teh onClick but its value changes so that doesn't make sense (it's first initalized as "" and then assigned a value that I get from an API).

The text I'm trying to get is the one inside of the TextView with id parentTitle in a CardView. I have several of these cardViews. I don't know if it's relevant but here's the code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playRoutine"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/play_gris"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parentTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/expandArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/expande_de_lista"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this -

```
public TitleParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_routines, viewGroup, false);
ImageView playIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playRoutine);
TextView rutNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parentTitle);
playIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String rutName = rutNameView.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), rutName + " was played",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
return new TitleParentViewHolder(view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below declaration code before `playIcon.setOnClickListener`

```
TextView rutNameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.parentTitle);
```